# MacVim Replace All Issue

Tags: macos, macvim

I have an html file that I need to replace some characters with html entities.  Right now I'm trying to replace **—** with **&mdash;** but when I use the *Replace All* button, the result is that all of those instances of **—** are replaced with **—mdash;**

I thought maybe escaping the "&" will work, so I changed the *Replace with* value to **\&mdash;** but that just results in **\—mdash;**

The strange thing is that if I go to each, one by one, i.e., click *Next*, then click *Replace*, and so on, then it replaces it correctly.

Is this a bug in MacVim? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Enter into command line:

```
:%s/—/\&mdash;/g
```

Also it's possible to get character code. Place your cursor on the character and press **ga**. Use  decimal, hex or octal code into replacement string:

```
\%d match specified decimal character
\%x match specified hex character
\%o match specified octal character
\%u match specified multibyte character 
\%U match specified large multibyte character

:%s/\%d8212/\$mdash;/g
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining why the Replace all doesn't work? I feel like such a trivial task shouldn't require this much work :)